# Insert an identity matrix into a larger dimension of null matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

Suppose i have an identity matrix .

```
I=eye(3)
```

which will produce

```
I = [1 0 0
       0 1 0
       0 0 1]
```

Now i want to insert I into a (5X5) null matrix such that my result will be

```
N = [0 0 0 0 0 
     0 0 0 0 0 
     0 0 1 0 0
     0 0 0 1 0
     0 0 0 0 1]
```

How could i achieve this efficiently .Thanks in advace

Comment: With IP toolbox - `padarray(I,[2 2],'pre')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively,

```
m = 5;
n = 3;
a = diag( [zeros(1, m-n), ones(1,n)] );
```

Answer (score 3):

With the Image processing toolbox, this could be done using [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/padarray.html?refresh=true) like this:

```
padarray(eye(3), [2 2], 'pre');
```

`padarray` pads an array with zeros. The `[2 2]` part says how many zeros to pad it with, in this case 2 rows and 2 columns. `pre` means you want it in front of the matrix, not after it (`post`).

Without it, you need to tweak it a bit more. One option could be to create an identity matrix of the full size, then make the first elements zero:

```
m = 5;  %// size of matrix
n = 3;  %// size of identity matrix
a = eye(m);
a(1:m-n,1:m-n) = 0;
a =
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1
```

... or:

```
a = zeros(m);
a(m-n+1:m,m-n+1:m) = eye(n)
```

... or using [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
full(sparse(m-n+1:m,m-n+1:m,1))
```

Comment: @ Robert P , Thank you very much sir . Your explanations are very much helpful for a begnnier like me. Have a good day !